# Discord window.localStorage is undefined. How to get access to the localStorage on Discord page?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, discord

When I run `window.localStorage` on `https://stackoverflow.com` it returns the `localStorage` but when I use the same command on Discord page it returns `undefined` every time.

Is there something that Discord is doing to remove their `localStorage` from the client side? And if so, is there a way to change the `localStorage` before it is removed, prevent it from being removed or any other way to somehow access it before it is `undefined`?

Anything help?

Comment: Have you confirmed that Discord is actually *using* localStorage? The fact that it is coming back undefined almost assuredly indicates that it is not. Or at least, it's being deleted after the event.

Comment: they `delete window.localStorage` after saving a reference to it to prevent people from accessing sensitive data programmatically.

Comment: @AmerllicA, you can not only see all it – you can have the full access to all values from this `localStorage`. See **[my solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778878)**.

Comment: Dear @AmerllicA, on **[this address](https://discordapp.com)** You don't need even to have to be logged in to your Discord account.

Answer (score 32):

You can still obtain access programmatically. They’ve deleted [`window.localStorage`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-localstorage-attribute). This is an [own-property](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#ref-for-dfn-interface-member%E2%91%A1%E2%93%AA) of window instances, but it’s not a data property, it’s an [accessor](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#ref-for-define-the-regular-attributes%E2%91%A0). The accessor’s `get` function will return the `localStorage` value associated with any appropriate receiver (`this` arg)*. Deleting the `localStorage` accessor has no impact on whether the object itself exists, so all you’ll need to do to access it again is find another `get localStorage()` function. Fortunately, you can obtain one many ways — every Window object gets created with one.

```js
// If we create an <iframe> and connect it to our document, its
// contentWindow property will return a new Window object with
// a freshly created `localStorage` property. Once we obtain the
// property descriptor, we can disconnect the <iframe> and let it
// be collected — the getter function itself doesn’t depend on
// anything from its origin realm to work**.

function getLocalStoragePropertyDescriptor() {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.head.append(iframe);
  const pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(iframe.contentWindow, 'localStorage');
  iframe.remove();
  return pd;
}

// We have several options for how to use the property descriptor
// once we have it. The simplest is to just redefine it:

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', getLocalStoragePropertyDescriptor());

window.localStorage.heeeeey; // yr old friend is bak

// You can also use any function application tool, like `bind` or `call`
// or `apply`. If you hold onto a reference to the object somehow, it
// won’t matter if the global property gets deleted again, either.

const localStorage = getLocalStoragePropertyDescriptor().get.call(window);
```

If this is an arms race thing, the party interested in hiding localStorage could attempt patching every method and accessor throughout the DOM that could return a reference to a window object whose localStorage property has not already been deleted. That’s harder to do than might be obvious. Even if they succeeded, though, the final word will remain on the user side: a browser extension’s manifest can declare a content script that will be evaluated before any other code when the document loads. Even a CSP can’t prevent it. (On one hand this sucks ... on the other, without that capability, adblocking extensions could never work.)

The Storage API, whether sessionStorage or localStorage, isn’t meant for holding sensitive data. It’s not protected at all. An attempt to hide it is a hint that it may be getting misused — you might want to be careful about entering sensitive data on that site if its authors are under the impression that deleting the property is providing some kind of security.

> * An appropriate receiver here would be any window object that hasn’t had storage disabled by the user (e.g. Safari incognito) and which has a ‘non-opaque’ origin (meaning for example that it doesn’t work in the browser’s `about:blank` page, since storage needs to be associated with a normal origin).
>
> **Aside: bonus curio regarding global branded attributes.**
>
> ** It doesn’t depend on its origin realm *normally,* anyway. Properties created from Web IDL attributes on [Global] interfaces can exhibit a unique behavior when the receiver is null or undefined, though, where the origin realm can become significant. If we were to call the `get` function with *no* receiver, e.g.
>
> ```js
> const { get } = getLocalStoragePropertyDescriptor();
> get(); // ... null?
> ```
>
> ...then it would, instead of throwing a TypeError like is typical, return null. In fact, all platform attributes, not just those on [Global] interfaces, have a default receiver. The default receiver, which kicks in if the given receiver is null or undefined, is the global object of the realm where the function was created. What’s different for the [Global] case is that this default can actually be, and usually is, a *valid* receiver — i.e. it can be an object that really does implement the interface whose attribute this is (any other functions would still end up throwing the same TypeError, so you’d never know about this default receiver).
>
> In that example, it defaults to the window object from the original iframe. It tries to grab its `localStorage` object, but because the iframe is long gone, it instead returns null. I’m not actually sure where that last behavior is specified. I’m guessing it’s *not* specified, actually, since it contradicts the IDL definition for the attribute. It makes sense though (it’s gotta do something), and it’s what Chrome does. In Firefox, attempting this leads to an internal engine error, suggesting this edge case might just not have gotten a lot of consideration.

Comment: I like this solution because it restores window.localStorage and does not require an iframe to stay inserted, also the explanation of how it works is pretty good. Also one of you guys downvoted this answer to bump your own.

Comment: also his answer removed the iframe which makes it not work :P

Answer (score 4):

Like user AkiraMiura has already mentioned - "Discord" page developers had deleted the `window.localStorage` property. They had done it like follows (citate from **[Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7girg9/how_does_discord_hide_localstorage/)**):

> **How does Discord hide localStorage?**
>   ....
>
> ```
> (function()
> {
>     var privateLocalStorage = window.localStorage;
>     delete window.localStorage;
>     console.log(privateLocalStorage);
> }());
> console.log(window.localStorage); //undefined
> ```
>
> They create a closure where all of their local storage operations are and copy `localStorage` to a variable and then delete the object from the window.

**But we can use localStorage from iframes**

If you want to <s>restore</s> use the **localStorage** on Discord page then you can take it from a new iframe with `iframe.src = 'about:blank';` This gives you the possibility to work with stored items for "Discord" page. You could write:

```
window.localStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage;
```

after iframe load, but this `localStorage` object is from iframe and because of this you do not need to write it so - better is like in my code below.

The following code you can put on **["Discord" page](https://discordapp.com)** in developer console and you will get in console output something like this:

> "45235333...WKDrSWDKIS"

<s>Do not forget to login on "Discord" page before!</s> (you don't need to have to be logged in on this page even).

**Code**

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function()
{
    //Iframes must be appended to the DOM in order to be loaded
    //Iframes do not load immediately nor synchronously
    //now (after load) we can use iframe.contentWindow:
    //window.localStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage; //you can use it, but better is like:
    var ifrLocalStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage;
    //But DO NOT: "document.body.removeChild(iframe);" because after it access on 'Storage' will be denied
    console.log(ifrLocalStorage.getItem('fingerprint'));
    //OUTPUT: "45235333...WKDrSWDKIS"
};
iframe.src = 'about:blank';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

*Good luck!*

Comment: contentWindow is available synchronously. load is asynchronous. a loaded document isn’t required here; skipping src and onload works the same.

Answer (score 1):

Found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7girg9/how_does_discord_hide_localstorage/). TL;DR, they move their window.localStorage to another variable then delete window.localStorage.

One way I found to get the localStorage (Although Manually) is as follows:

1: goto `%AppData%/discord/Local Storage/`

2: open `https_discordapp.com_0.localstorage` in SQLite Studio

3: goto `https_discordapp.com_0 > Tables > ItemTable` and double click it.

4: under the `Data` tab double click a value and read/convert the hex data removing every other `00` hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
(() => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.onload = function() {
                            var ifrLocalStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage;
                            
                            // Store the reference to the localStorage from the iframe
                            window.localStorage = ifrLocalStorage; 

                            // Try to get the 'token' that was previously stored
                            var token = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
                            resolve(token); // Resolve the promise with the value
                        };
                        iframe.src = 'about:blank';
                        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                    });
                })();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).