# Chrome is unable to get localStorage

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to make a script with which you can automatically login to discord using your token. However when I try to do `window.localStorage.setItem("token", "value");` it just sais
`selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'setItem' of undefined`.
So if `window.localStorage` is undefined, how can I change that and access the local storage?

Here is my full code if it helps:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

token = input("Enter User Token:\n  -> ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.discord.com/login")
driver.execute_script(f"window.localStorage.setItem('token', '{token}');")
driver.refresh()
```

**Edit:**
My final code is available on [this](https://github.com/RealMoondancer/DiscordTokenLogin) GitHub Repo. (https://github.com/RealMoondancer/DiscordTokenLogin)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it's possible a script is using the variable "localStorage" and it's unitialized.  Try setting that.  Use var localStorage = window.localStorage;   Then localStorage.setItem(...

Comment: I tested it for other pages and it seems only this page doesn't  have `window.localStorage`. Or maybe it blocks it for security reason.

Comment: If someone wants my final code, I uploaded it here: https://github.com/RealMoondancer/DiscordTokenLogin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested `window.localStorage` for other pages and only this page doesn't have it.

After checking word `localStorage` in all JavaScript files I found in

https://discord.com/assets/43c944f57ecd3f83e53c.js

line

```
delete window.localStorage
```

which removes this object - and this makes problem.

I think they do this for security reason.

Before `delete` there is also

```
r=window.localStorage
```

which can means they assign it to variable `r` to keep access but this variable doesn't work for me. Probably they assign it later to some other variable but code is obfuscated and I couldn't recognize where they assign it.

---

**EDIT:**

After checking in Google I found similar question

[Discord window.localStorage is undefined. How to get access to the localStorage on Discord page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509440/discord-window-localstorage-is-undefined-how-to-get-access-to-the-localstorage)

with answer which shows how to recreate access to `localStorage`.

```
// If we create an <iframe> and connect it to our document, its
// contentWindow property will return a new Window object with
// a freshly created `localStorage` property. Once we obtain the
// property descriptor, we can disconnect the <iframe> and let it
// be collected — the getter function itself doesn’t depend on
// anything from its origin realm to work**.

function getLocalStoragePropertyDescriptor() {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.head.append(iframe);
  const pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(iframe.contentWindow, 'localStorage');
  iframe.remove();
  return pd;
}

// We have several options for how to use the property descriptor
// once we have it. The simplest is to just redefine it:

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', getLocalStoragePropertyDescriptor());

window.localStorage.heeeeey; // yr old friend is bak

// You can also use any function application tool, like `bind` or `call`
// or `apply`. If you hold onto a reference to the object somehow, it
// won’t matter if the global property gets deleted again, either.

const localStorage = getLocalStoragePropertyDescriptor().get.call(window);
```

and this works for me when I test it in JavaScript console (for page `discord.com`)

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def test1(driver, url, token='abc'):

    print('[test1] url:', url) 
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        driver.execute_script(f"window.localStorage.setItem('token', '{token}');")
        driver.refresh()

        print('[test1] get token:', driver.execute_script(f"return window.localStorage.getItem('token');") )
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)
        
def test2(driver, url, token='abc'):
    recreate_localStorage_script = '''
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.head.append(iframe);
    const pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(iframe.contentWindow, 'localStorage');
    iframe.remove();    
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', pd);
    '''

    print('[test2] url:', url) 
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(1)
    
    try:
        driver.execute_script(recreate_localStorage_script)
        driver.execute_script(f"window.localStorage.setItem('token', '{token}');")
        driver.refresh()

        driver.execute_script(recreate_localStorage_script)
        print('[test2] get token:', driver.execute_script(f"return window.localStorage.getItem('token');") )
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    token = 'abc'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    #driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # raise error when you try to use localStorage: "SecurityError: The operation is insecure."
                                  # selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

    test1(driver, "https://httpbin.org/get", token)    # OK
    test1(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com", token)  # OK if it sleeps few (milli)seconds
    test1(driver, "https://discord.com/login", token)  # ERROR

    test2(driver, "https://httpbin.org/get", token)    # OK
    test2(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com", token)  # OK
    test2(driver, "https://discord.com/login", token)  # OK
```

---

**BTW:**

When I try to use `localStorage` in `Firefox` then it raises error

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: 
 Message: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

It may need something else to resolve this problem.

---

**EDIT:**

For other visitors: as @Moondancer mentioned in comment it works if `token` is in `" "` like this

```
driver.execute_script(f"window.localStorage.setItem('token', '\"{token}\"');")
```

Comment: I added minimal working example which I used to test problem.

Comment: Btw if you want to login to discord you have to change `driver.execute_script(f"window.localStorage.setItem('token', '{token}');")` with `driver.execute_script(f"window.localStorage.setItem('token', '\"{token}\"');")` because the value has to be in "".

Comment: did you made it ? did you login with localStorage?

Comment: yes I have successfully logged in using localStorage. Just add the token as the value sorroundet by "" and as the key use `token` and refresh the site.

Comment: I add this information to answer so other visitors will see it.

Comment: I added the link to the github repo where my final code is as a comment to my question and now as an edit on the question itself

Comment: seems like that iframe would need to be set to the same page/domain.  I think localstorage will be tied to domain.