# First attempt requires login, subsequent attempts do not. How to create IF statement or another way to check whether login required?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium I want to access "discordapp.com/users/{user_id}" where `{user_id}` is my Discord ID. On creating the session the initial attempt works fine:

1. the URL is loaded redirects to "discord.com/channels/@me"
2. displays a page asking whether to open in app or continue in browser
3. "Continue in browser" is clicked
4. Discord login form is displayed, and login info is entered and "Log In" is clicked
5. Discord web app is displayed

However, on subsequent attempts to run the function within the same session, the "Continue in browser" and "Log In" steps are not required, so Selenium's `wait.until` never finds these elements and the script does not proceed. See code below:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = uc.options.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False, "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={UserAgent().random}')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def x_discord(user_id):
    
    driver.get(f"https://discordapp.com/users/{user_id}")
    try:
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Continue in browser')]"))).click()
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys('login')
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys('password')
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Log In')]"))).click()
    finally:
        wait.until(ec.url_contains("@me"))
   
    #rest of function...     
   
    #driver.close()
    return result
```

Again, the initial run works as intended, it's the subsequent runs that fail due to login process no longer being required as the full logged in page now loads.

Things I've tried/considered:

1. Using Selenium's `wait.until(ec.url_to_be(url))`, but the URL is always "discord.com/channels/@me" after the initial redirect from "https://discordapp.com/users/{user_id}"
2. Integrate some sort of counter that sets a variable to "1" from "0" after the initial run, and have the function check this counter before proceeding each time.
3. I tried using `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` in hopes of "resetting" the state of the page each time, but for some reason it seems Selenium will not start a new session when either of these are used.

I'm just now realizing that the `try, finally` may not be doing what I think since the URL will generally always contain "@me", but again the code functions as intended on the initial run.

Any thoughts on this or suggestions for a better way would be GREATLY appreciated. I am still VERY much learning and only have a few months of coding under my belt. Thank you for your time.

UPDATE

Updated code with example you provided:

```
def x_discord(user_id):
    
    driver.get(f"https://discordapp.com/users/{user_id}")
    user_email = driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.getItem('email_cache');")
    if user_email:
        pass
    else:
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Continue in browser')]"))).click()
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys('login')
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys('password')
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Log In')]"))).click()
:
        #wait.until(ec.url_contains("@me"))
   
    #rest of function...     
   
    #driver.close()
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`driver.get_cookie(name)`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookie). The login process will have set a cookie (check with your browser for exact name), then you can just check for its presence in selenium.

This should be more reliable in case the login flow changes, which is more common than the cookie name changing.

---

**Edit**

It seems that Discord always sets the same cookies (`__cf_bm`, `__cfruid`, `__dcfduid`, and `__sdcfduid`) regardless of login status. Checking the browser state is still my suggested solution, but we have to find another method.

Thankfully, it sets many entries in `localStorage`, the most straightforward being `email_cache`. We can get it by combining Selenium's [`execute_script`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) with the browser's [`storage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

```py
user_email = driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.getItem('email_cache');")
if user_email: print('Logged in!')
```

As a bonus, you can verify that the logged in email is the one you expected.

---

**Edit 2**

It seems that Discord [tries really hard to prevent people from doing this sort of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509440/discord-window-localstorage-is-undefined-how-to-get-access-to-the-localstorage).

More specifically, Discord deletes the `localStorage` property from the global window. Using the link above I created the following script that tries a hack to get the value again:

```py
arms_race_str = "iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); document.head.append(iframe); value = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage.getItem('email_cache'); iframe.remove(); return value;"
user_email = driver.execute_script(arms_race_str)
if user_email: print('Logged in!')
```

This is getting ugly, so as an alternative-alternative solution, you can also try to identify elements in the page that are only present for logged in users. It could be an id (perhaps the logout button?), or a piece of text (the name of the logged-in user).

Comment: Fantastic idea. I'm checking out the page cookies in Dev Tools now. It looks like Discord loads a cookie called "__cf_bm" on the login page, and then loads another cookie with the exact same name once logged in. The "__cf_bm" cookie loaded after log in is the ONLY cookie loaded on this page. I'm assuming this will be a problem as `if driver.get_cookie('__cf_bm')` will return `True` for both pages. This is still helpful as maybe I can craft a `not` condition using the other cookies loaded prior to logging in.

Comment: @JaredRobertson Ah, that's a shame. I edited the answer with another option along the same line: `localStorage`. I can't test the webdriver myself, but the entries are set correctly when I visit from the browser.

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated answer. I checked cookies in Local Storage and sure enough `email_cache` loads on logging in. Your response makes sense and it should work, but for some reason calling `execute_script()`*** is hanging up the script. I used your example exactly and tried a couple of different scenarios. Tried the `if user_email` with a `wait.until(url_to_be...)`, with `pass` and `wait.until` outside the IF statement, and with pass and without the `wait.until` at all. The initial page with the "Continue in browser" button loads and then nothing happens. Will add code update

Comment: @JaredRobertson If you are using the localStorage solution, you shouldn't use `get_cookie` at all, they are separate data stores. But I also noticed that Discord blocks access to `localStorage`, so I posted an alternative way to access it.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! That 100% did the trick! I really can't thank you enough. Amazing, informative answers. I've learned a ton.